# Column Visibility based on Multiple multi value parameters SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that needs to toggle the visibility of a column based on the values from two different multi valued parameters.  The code below joins each parameter to a "" and then searches with IntStr for a specific value.  The column visibility should be on if both parameters have these values.  Can anyone help me identify why this does not work?

```
=IIF((InStr(Join(Parameters!Metrics.Value,""),"S") AND 
InStr(Join(Parameters!ProductGroup.Value,""),"OS")), False, True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InStr function returns integer value of Starting position of occurrence of character in string. So, the expression should be.. 
=IIF((InStr(Join(Parameters!Metrics.Value,""),"S")>0 AND 
InStr(Join(Parameters!ProductGroup.Value,""),"OS"))>0, False, True)